# Can I reprogram a microphone input to be used as an audio output? (on XP)

Tags: windows-xp, audio

I have a five year old Sony Vaio laptop (vgn-fw31m) that has had impact damage to the audio-output mini-jack for about the last year or so. In a recent discussion with my brother, we wondered whether it would be possible to write a program that would enable windows to use the microphone mini-jack input as the audio-output? As I currently use this laptop for work I am not keen to risk pulling it apart in order to replace the components comprising the audio-out. I therefore 'hope' that a programming solution exists. I would really appreciate any advice on this and eagerly await your response. Kind regards,

qftme :)

Comment: Unless there's some special hardware in the unit to enable this, it's not possible.  You should be able to get someone to fix the output jack (maybe just with wires hanging out) for a relatively small charge.  Or get a USB-to-audio adapter.

Answer (score 2):

It's *possible* your hardware could support this - as microphones and speakers are, in large part, the same structures being used differently. I doubt it though, as the audio hardware is probably rigged to amplify in one direction only - that just makes sense.

IF you could do this, you'll likely need to get the source code for your audio driver and edit it.

However, unless you're really comfortable with that kind of thing already, or unless you have insane amounts of free time, I think you're out of luck.

I suppose it may be worth your time to take a closer look at that broken jack and see if you might be able to fix that too. There's not a lot of parts involved with that, basically 3 wires and something to keep them oriented properly.

But being realistic, I suggest you look for a USB solution, such as a USB sound card, or, perhaps USB headphones. Fortunately for you, at least it's a pretty old laptop anyway.

Comment: You wrote "IF you could do this, you'll likely need to get the source code for your video driver and edit it." Don't you mean "*sound* driver"?

Comment: Heh, well.. yeah.. Don't get me wrong video driver editing could be a riot in its own right. But indeed, I meant sound driver - I'll edit this now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know some realtek audio cards would actually ask you what you plugged in as soon as you plugged in a jack, regardless of the actual port you plug it into, you could configure it as whatever you wanted... But it all depends on the type of audio card that is installed in your computer. I would say that 95% of the time either it is not possible whit that hardware, or extremely difficult.

You best bet would be to buy a cheap usb to audio adapter, something similar to this: [http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16829128002&cm_re=usb_to_audio_adapter-*-29-128-002-*-Product](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16829128002&cm_re=usb_to_audio_adapter-_-29-128-002-_-Product)

Comment: yep there are plenty of USB audio dongles out there that can do this

Answer (score 0):

No that isn't possible. It's a hardware issue.

The electronic circuitry attached to a microphone jack differs from the electronic circuitry attached to a line-out, headphone-out or speaker-out jack.